# Typescript error on return subject.asObservable()

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, observable, typescript-generics

I have a question I hope you can help me with. Thanks

After upgrading to Typescript 2.9.1 the compiler is complaining for not returning the type that the method supposed to return.

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
public getCardPairingSession(sessionId:string):Observable<FundSourceCardSessionInterface> {
    const subject = new Subject();

    this.apiService
      .get(this.buildApiPath('card-session/' + sessionId))
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          subject.next(response.result);
        },
        (error) => {
          subject.error(error);
        }
      );
/* <-- ERROR: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<FundSourceCardSessionInterface>' */
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

**MY SOLUTION:**

so far, I am casting my return by doing, although I do not know if its correct, looks odd to me.

```
return  <Observable<FundSourceCardSessionInterface>> subject.asObservable();
```

**QUESTION:**

If before with Typescript 2.3.4 was working fine, now I don't understand why it does not?, why do I have to cast the return if I already specified which return to expect at the beginning of the method? basically is duplicating code:

```
public getCardPairingSession(sessionId:string):Observable<FundSourceCardSessionInterface> {
```

Comment: Did you try declaring the Subject as `const subject = new Subject<FundSourceCardSessionInterface>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clear: You are declaring the function as returning `Observable<FundSourceCardSessionInterface>` and you're returning `Observable<{}>`. I think (not completely sure) that, prior, TypeScript understood that you were returning `Observable<any>`, and `Observable<any>` is assignable to `Observable<FundSourceCardSessionInterface>`. However, `{}` is not assignable to `FundSourceCArdSessionInterface`.

Change the way in which you're declariong your `Subject`:

```
const subject = new Subject<FundSourceCardSessionInterface>();`
```

Comment: ohhh that way better than casting in the return, Thanks!